# Update Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update temp table in sql 2014 but this code seems wrong .
first i select all invoices and its Qty from invoices and set Inventory Qty with 0. and second statement i need to update each line by qty of inventory to compare later and use this code.

```
declare @DifferenceTable  table (
        DataAreaId nvarchar(10) ,
        SalesId nvarchar(50) ,
        InvoiceId nvarchar(50) ,
        ItemId nvarchar(50),
        InvoiceQty decimal(16,4) ,
        InventoryQty decimal(16,4)
    )
```

`` insert into @DifferenceTable (DataAreaId , SalesId , InvoiceId , ItemId , InvoiceQty ,  InventoryQty )
    select CustInvoiceTrans.DATAAREAID , CustInvoiceTrans.SALESID , CustInvoiceTrans.INVOICEID , CustInvoiceTrans.ITEMID , sum(CustInvoiceTrans.QTY) , 0. as InventoryQty
    from CustInvoiceTrans with(nolock)    
    group by CustInvoiceTrans.DATAAREAID , CustInvoiceTrans.SALESID , CustInvoiceTrans.INVOICEID , CustInvoiceTrans.ITEMID

update @DifferenceTable
    set InventoryQty =  tt.Qty from 
                                           (select sum(InventTrans.QTY)*-1 as Qty , InventTransOrigin.DATAAREAID , REFERENCEID , InventTrans.INVOICEID , InventTrans.ITEMID
                                            from InventTransOrigin 
                                             left join InventTrans      on InventTrans.INVENTTRANSORIGIN = InventTransOrigin.RECID 
                                                                                    and InventTrans.DATAAREAID = InventTransOrigin.DATAAREAID
                                                                                    and InventTrans.ITEMID = InventTransOrigin.ITEMID
                                             where REFERENCECATEGORY = 0 
                                             group by InventTransOrigin.DATAAREAID , REFERENCEID , InventTrans.INVOICEID , InventTrans.ITEMID
                                            ) tt
                                    where  @DifferenceTable.DataAreaId =  tt.DATAAREAID and @DifferenceTable.SalesId = tt.REFERENCEID
                                    and tt.INVOICEID = @DifferenceTable.InvoiceId and tt.ITEMID = @DifferenceTable.ItemId   

select * from @DifferenceTable` ``

Comment: What is your actual question. What are you expecting from this code and what are getting. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question and provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic you are implementing . . . and a question.

Comment: Please mention what is your Problem. Is it that you are getting wrong results or getting some exceptions? Also Please add some sample data and try to give a demo of your actual issue